# how important is a partition schema for xen guests?

Tags: vps, xen, partition

i recently came across this [post](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/the-importance-of-linux-partitions.html) on the importance of partitions, and was impressed, but is this relevant for servers running as guests in xen?  if so, how/what do i partition?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

it does not matter if you have a xen guest or a hardware system, you should partition it.
The post contains a first idee of how to partition your system. Perhaps you want to go a bit further by adding additional partitions for `/var/log` and `/opt`, but it depends on your system setup, how much logs are generated and where you install any additional software or where you save e.g. database files.

Another good practice is to use LVM when possible. This way your system is more flexible and it is easier to make adjustments when your requirements change.

Comment: thanks, Christian.  i'm new to xen and still trying to wrap my head around the idea of partitioning a virtual disk.  when i ran fdisk -l on the domU's mount point, it only shows a single partition. is this what i split into multiple partitions, or is that an actual hardware partition?  can you recommend a tutorial or documentation for this process?  thanks again

Comment: Hi erik,

here is a tutorial for installing centos on a domu:
http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Xen/InstallingCentOSDomU


They use the virtual disk as normal device and set up LVM on it.